# El documento HTML no me muestra el console.log del JS

Tags: javascript, html, script

estoy empezando con JS (tengo nociones de Java) y al realizar la prueba de realizar el console.log, tanto dentro del html como en un .js a parte, este no muestra nada. Pego a continuación el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>console.log("Hello world!")</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

He probado con window.alert y funciona correctamente. Tengo instalado node.js y he cambiado la ruta.

Sé que es un problema de principiante pero no tengo ni idea de cómo solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al convertir tu código a snippet (en la pregunta, con el botón que indica `<>`) se imprime en la consola, tal como se espera. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Por si acaso: `console.log` imprime en la consola **del navegador** (ya que mencionaste que usás Node.JS). Consola del navegador != terminal.

Comment: Para ver la salida de `console.log` debes abrir la consola del navegador. Presiona F12 y se abrirán las web developer tools, donde encontrarás la consola del navegador. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JavaScript no tiene tanto que ver con Java, el nombre se lo pusieron por puro marketing.
2. Tu código si escribe a consola.
3. Lo que creo que quieres hacer es escribir en la página, para eso tienes que usar la función de escribir en el documento, no la consola:

```js
document.write("Hello World");
```